# Zend Framework 2 getQuery() returns null

Tags: zend-framework2

I am learning about the request class.

I have this url `http://localahost/blog/search?year=2013&month=07`

When i try `print_r($_GET)` it returns the array as expected.

When i try `print_r($request->getQuery());`
It returns an empty object `Zend\Stdlib\Parameters Object ( [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array ( ) )`

So `echo $request->getQuery()->year;` returns nothing...

My .htaccess (if needed)

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: how did u intialize/Call "$request"?

Comment: in my controller `use Zend\Http\Request;` and in my function `$request = new Request;`

Comment: dont do this $request = new Request;. I assume you are new and are using extends AbstractActionController. With your class, if you are using it then. you dont need to create new object

Comment: tell me are you using extends AbstractActionController or not

Comment: i have to use `$this->getQuery()`? If yes it returns `Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for getQuery`

Comment: yes i use `AbstractActionController`

Comment: ok if you are using so then you dont have to $request = new Request;.
Instead do some thing like this $request=$this->getRequest(); and then $request->getQuery(). And then see what happens

Comment: thank you very much! please write your answer below to check it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WHat you are doing as Mentioned in your Comments was that you are Doing

```
$request= new $request();
```

What you need to know is that when you extend a class with **AbstractActionController** you dont need to do **$request= new $request()**. **AbstractActionController** provides you

```
getRequest()
```

from which you can fetch request and its data.